# Can you rehydrate phyllo dough?

Tags: dough, dehydrating

I like eating food with phyllo dough and I like preparing such food. However, phyllo dough is not easily available where I live. The only packages I can find are rather large. I usually use how much I need, then cover it as best as I can and store it air-tight in the freezer for later use. If I thaw and refreeze and rethaw some sheets, they tend to get dry.

Even just working with non-frozen phyllo dough, can make your sheets dry out if you don't work quickly an/or with a wet towel.

I was wondering if you could do anything to reverse this process. Is there a way to rehydrate phyllo sheets?

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't tried- I just buy more. The wet towel over a container might work. You can't have contact with the water or else it will get mushy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think rehydrating evenly is going to be very dicey. Instead, when you first open a large pack, immediately separate it into smaller batches, wrapping each tightly in wax paper and then a zip-loc removing as much air as possible, and re-freezing those smaller packs. Now you won't have to thaw and refreeze any sheets more than once - just grab the number of smaller packs you need. This should keep them in better condition.

Comment: I came in to say this. Repackage and re freeze smaller batches! Definitely the way to go. Melting ice crystals in the butter will tear your fats to shreds and make soggy, flatter dough in the final preparation.